# Can i play multiple songs with single MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I have to 2 songs.I used radio buttons for both songs so when select first it should play me the first song and when i click on second. Second song should be played.I have used Play,pause and stop button so when i select first song and click play first song should be played.how to use media player for 2 songs.Previously i used 2 media players for different songs. How to use one media player.
Previously I have used this statements for two songs

```
mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.inno); 

mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.rocky);
```

My question is i want to use only one media player for both songs

Comment: You can do [`setDataSource`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.lang.String%29) etc once you click the button.

Comment: can any one help me regarding this issue

Answer (score 1):

You better stop being lazy and search for the solution on your own aswell. @1Up pretty much answered your question. For your second question: [This is Uri](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Uri.html)

Comment: Brother I have 2 songs in res folder and two media players for different songs.i want use one media player for both the songs previously i have written the code                             mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.inno);

mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.drawable.rocky);            now i want to use the only one media player how can use

Comment: reply me i am not lazy your lazy to answer my question ok

Comment: MediaPlayer.setDatasource(path);

Answer (score 0):

Keep using two mediaplayers, in cases like this there is no problem doing that. Using only one reference would mean you'd have to recreate it each time you want to change clip, or stopping it and calling setDataSource(context, URI).

If you use only one reference to mediaplayer the user will have to wait for the clip to be ready each time it has to be played, while in your implementation both sound clips are ready to be played at any time.

Anyways, here is a setDataSource example:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, firstSongUriOrRes);

public void play(int clip)
{
    if(mp.isPlaying())    //Stop the mediaplayer if it's already playing
        mp.stop();
    switch(clip)          //Choose the clip to be played
    {
        case 0:
            mp.setDataSource(context, firstSongUriOrRes);
            break;
        case 1:
            mp.setDataSource(context, secondSongUriOrRes);
            break;
    }
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();           //Start the mediaplayer
}
```

Another way to use setDataSource is to place the audio files inside the asset directory and use this code:

```
AssetFileDescriptor fd = context.getAssets().openFd("pathInsideAssets/fileName");
mp.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(), fd.getStartOffset(), fd.getDeclaredLength());
```

Comment: what is uri if i am giving the path of song i.e.,R.drawable.inno it is giving me error in this statement mp.setDataSource(); i want know wht is uri? is it web link???

Comment: it is asking me change the type inno to uri

Comment: If you are inside an activity, the context is "this"

Comment: it is asking change type to uri

Comment: it is asking me to change type to uri what should i change in this statement  mp.setDataSource(this, secondSongUriOrRes);

Comment: I don't know how to get an URI from a resource file, so I added a way to use setDataSource with Asset files. As far as I know, you cannot call setDataSource only with a resID.

Comment: Should i use the code also  public void play(int clip)
{
    if(mp.isPlaying())    //Stop the mediaplayer if it's already playing
        mp.stop();
    switch(clip)          //Choose the clip to be played
    {
        case 0:
            mp.setDataSource(context, firstSongUriOrRes);
            break;
        case 1:
            mp.setDataSource(context, secondSongUriOrRes);
            break;
    }
    mp.prepare();
    mp.start();           //Start the mediaplayer
}